# Type hint for a list of datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, type-hinting

I have a function bellow that takes two arguments:

1. a `list` (or `tuple`) of `datetime`
2. `datetime` object. It checks if my `datetime` object is withing the range or not.

```
import datetime
from typing import (
    Optional,
    Union,
    List,
)

def time_in_range(time_range: Optional[List[datetime]], my_time: datetime) -> bool:
    """Return true if my_time is in the range [start, end]"""
    state=time_range[0]
    end=time_range[1]
    if start <= end:
        return start <= my_time <= end
    else:
        return start <= my_time or my_time <= end
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Parameters to generic types must be types. Got <module 'datetime'>
```

Not sure what is the issue with declaring it this way?

Comment: `datetime` is indeed a module. It defines _types_ like `datetime.datetime`, `datetime.date`, ...

Comment: from datetime import datetime

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
from datetime import datetime
```

With your current import, `datetime` is the module containing the `datetime` object.

Comment: Or you can typehint with datetime.datetime which is also fair)

Comment: Right :) I am used to importing directly from the module, but your syntax works as well.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to Optional[List[datetime.datetime]]. How can I make it Optional between List and Tuple? Shall I use Union?

Comment: Yes, `Optional[Union[List, Tuple]]`. You can also consider using `Iterable` or `Sequence` as suggested here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List, But they contain more than lists and tuples though.

Comment: I get errors using this with Union: `Union[arg, ...]: each arg must be a type. Got <classmethod(<function Now.datetime at 0x000001F8519D6320>)>.`